# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_xml'

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Can you help me, I got this error, it refers to **init** file

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_text(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    text = r.text
    return text

def get_items(text, top_name, class_name):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html', 'html.parser')
    vac_list = soup.find('div', {'class': top_name})
    items = vac_list.find('h2', {'class': [class_name]})
    dirty_link = []
    for item in items:
        dirty_link.append(str(item.find('a')))
    return dirty_link

def get_links(dirty_list, start, end):
    links = []
    for row in dirty_list:
        if row != 'None':
            i_beg = row.find(start)
            i_end = row.find(end)
            if i_beg != -1 & i_end != -1:
                links.append(row[i_beg:i_end])
    return links

job_name = str(input("Введите интересующую должность:"))

url = "https://qyzmet.kz/vacansii?q="+str(job_name)+"&l=%D0%9D%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD"

top_name = 'jobs'
class_name = 'title'
start = 'vacancies'
end = '/">Отправить резюме'

text = get_text(url)
dirty_link = get_items(text, top_name, class_name)

links = get_links(dirty_link, start, end)
```

Traceback says that

```
  File "C:/Users/Милена/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/parser.py", line 39, in <module>
    dirty_link = get_items(text, top_name, class_name)
  File "C:/Users/Милена/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/parser.py", line 11, in get_items
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html', 'html.parser')
  File "C:\Users\Милена\Desktop\diplom\bot\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 301, in __init__
    self.is_xml = builder.is_xml
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_xml'
```

What is wrong with this code? I tried to search it, but couldn't find anything. Should I change html to xml in line 11? In this case it will ask for a builder :/

Comment: when having `BeautifulSoup(text, 'html', 'html.parser') ` extra 'html' is against the constructor definition of beautiful soup refer code at python3.8/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py, which is throwing the error. so remove 'html' when initializing the soup as suggested in answer section by @FantasqueX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)

> To parse a document, pass it into the BeautifulSoup constructor. You can pass in a string or an open filehandle:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html>a web page</html>", 'html.parser')
```

So line 13 of the code should be changed to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
```